# mysql: retry transaction specified number of times

Tags: mysql

I have an sql script which deletes large number of records from database. Script deletes records by small chunks:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `my_proc`;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc()
BEGIN
    DECLARE chunk_size INT DEFAULT 1000;

    main: LOOP
        SET @count= -1;
            
        START TRANSACTION;
            DELETE FROM my_table WHERE .... LIMIT chunk_size;
            SELECT ROW_COUNT() into @count;
        COMMIT;
            
        IF @count = 0 THEN             
            LEAVE main;
        END IF;
        DO SLEEP(0.1);     
    END LOOP main;
END$$           
            
DELIMITER ; 
    
CALL my_proc();                                                                                                       

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `my_proc`;
```

The problem is that DELETE statement may fail, so I want retry deletion of current chunk 10 times. So I want the script to fail only if the DELETE statement fails 10 times for current chunk.

I try to use `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1213 BEGIN ..... END;` but do not quite understand how to make it work. The main problem now is to make the script fail with meaningful (preferably original) error message if the `DELETE` failed 10 times.

Comment: 'DELETE statement may fail' - I dispute that, what kind of failure do you anticipate?

Comment: @P.Salmon Deadlock. I was very surprised, but that happens. It is some cluster and our architect confirmed assured me that this can happen.

Comment: If you architect knows then perhaps he can suggest a solution also have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlock-detection.html